# Is it possible to insert a column as a parameter in a user-defined function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to insert a column as a parameter in a user-defined function.

What I want to do is insert a column from a certain table and then return the minimum of that column when I call the function.
(For my purposes it's not the actual minimum that I want, I just want it to return one number, whether it be min, max, variance, standard deviation, or any other mathematical equation that gives me one scalar value).

Comment: Are you asking if you can `SELECT someFunction()`?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Are you looking for a user-defined aggregate? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131057.aspx

Comment: @RichardDeeming...it does seem like I might be looking for a user-defined aggregate...never used that before. I'll look into it and see what I can do.  I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use dynamic SQL using [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms188001.aspx)

```
CREATE procedure dbo.[myfunc](@COL NVARCHAR(20),
                             @result int output)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500)

SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @max_valueOUT = max(' + @COL + ') FROM mytable'
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@max_valueOUT int OUTPUT'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @max_valueOUT=@result OUTPUT
END
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8c766/18)

Comment: No, I did not. So, there  could be typos.

Comment: Sorry, I mean run it (it will compile but not run).

Comment: obviously, you need to have mytable in your database. When calling the function you need to pass a proper column, that has a type INT

Comment: It won't even get that far.

Comment: you right. You can't call stored procedures from within a function. So, it must be a stored procedure

Comment: thank you I will definitely try this out and see how it works!

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before. you have to create a User Defined Data Type. Then pass the user defined type into the function.